# Чтение файла с помощью ifstream

Tags: c++, linux, файлы

С текстом все еще хорошо. Использую:

```
...
char* filename=argv[1];
char content[_SIZE];//_SIZE=1024*1024*4
ifstream ifs(filename);
copy(ifstreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs),istreambuf_iterator<char>(),content);
content[_SIZE-1]=0;
...
```

Под новый год поверил в чудо, и подумал что такое прокатит с фалом .jpg...
Как лучше всего считать файл любого формата(txt jpg и т.п.)?

Comment: content у вас не массив символов, а массив указателей на символы,

Comment: если подумать то может и таким подходом можно, но ifstream  имеет те же возможности, что и любой istream + еще и свои как и любой класс наследник, поэтому не нужно придумывать велосипед,..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
ifstream ifs(filename,ios::binary);
size_t size = ifs.seekg(0,ios::end).tellg();
ifs.seekg(0);
char * buf = new char[size];
ifs.read(buf,size);
```

Comment: Для бинарных потоков 0 в сочетании с end ведет к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: @Croessmah А можно ссылку? раньше не слышал о таком.

Comment: http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/how-to-read-an-entire-file-into-memory-in-cpp/

Comment: @Croessmah Ну, начнем с того, что там **рассматривается функция C, а вывод делается для C++**. Далее, там речь идет о чтении многобайтных символов, о чем в нашем случае речь не идет. В книге, например, ["Язык С. Справочник"](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908911-6-6.html) ничего не сказано. В стандарте С++ о `seekg()` тоже ничего такого нет.

Comment: там же сказано, почему это относится и к C++ тоже. Собственно, причины также указаны. Да и никакого отношения к многобайтным символам там тоже нет.

Comment: Из стандарта C++ для basic_filebuf (27.9.1.1/2): The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an object of class basic_filebuf<charT, traits> are the same as for reading and writing with the Standard C library FILEs.

Comment: @Croessmah В любом случае забавно - тогда вообще непонятно, зачем вообще есть параметр SEEK_END. Хотел убрать свой ответ, чтоб не вызывать никаких споров - уже не дает... Тем не менее считаю это либо ошибкой разработчиков стандарта, либо - в самом лучшем случае - экзотикой типа 7-битного байта... О многобайтности - см., в каком разделе это приведено. А вообще, обоснование какое-то, мягко говоря, очень странное. Я имею в виду, не в статье, а в стандарте.

Comment: для текстовых потоков, например. )

Comment: @Croessmah Еще раз - мы работаем с бинарным файлом! Рассматриваемым как последовательность байт.

Comment: Да там вообще много чего не ясного. seekg основывается на pubseekg у буфера, а это значит, что всё поведение будет определяться буфером. И если оно не могёт чего-то, то и fstream тоже этого не могёт.